# Armory Bitcoin Wallet Code and GUI application

Tags: armory

I installed the Armory application a few days ago, i downloaded the zipped file from the Armory site and install it on my Linux OS, today I found out that I can actually build from code. So I built it from the code available on the VC. I run the ArmoryQt.py python script, it gives me an error:
e.g.

python ArmoryQt.py

---

Loading Armory Engine:
   Armory Version:       0.93.2
   Armory Build:         73b533cb2a
   PyBtcWallet  Version: 1.35
Detected Operating system: Linux
   OS Variant            : ('Ubuntu', '14.04', 'trusty')
   User home-directory   : /home/buildmds
   Satoshi BTC directory : /home/buildmds/.bitcoin/
   Armory home dir       : /home/buildmds/.armory/
   ArmoryDB directory     : /home/buildmds/.armory/databases
   Armory settings file  : /home/buildmds/.armory/ArmorySettings.txt
   Armory log file       : /home/buildmds/.armory/armorylog.txt
   Do wallet checking    : True
(ERROR) ArmoryQt.py:7085 - Socket already in use.  Sending CLI args to existing proc.
(ERROR) ArmoryQt.py:7089 - Exiting...

Does this mean it is conflicting with the other Armory application I installed?

Thanks for help, in advance

Comment: Looks like it is conflicting with an already running process, do you have another copy of Armory or Bitcoin Core open?

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much, I sorted it out,  i am using ssh and I installed two instances on the remote machine manual installation of Armory and building Armory.